# What are the security trends for client side coding in web development

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, backbone.js

There are a lots of new frameworks, technologies coming up. And it's becoming so hard to follow up all of them. One of the thing that confuses me is client side frameworks. I heard that Angularjs,Backbone,Knockout,jsviews,knockback, SPA... are the most popular right now.But I can't understand how does the security concept applies? If we take an example of querying a table form database it's now possible to make queries from client side database, by specifying table name and fields and etc... So if it works that way, than everyone else can write another query and get all other information. I am pretty sure that I am missing something very important here, and it doesn't click my mind. So please can anybody explain me where can I start learning those primitives.

I really appreciate, and I am really eager to learn but I am searching it wrong way I guess.

Comment: The old principles of what data should stay on the server still apply.

Comment: this review might help a bit: https://code.google.com/p/mustache-security/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whatever the framework used, the security matter will still the same, and very similar to mobile apps:

1. which data can you afford to be handled in an untrusted environnement
2. which treatment can be applied in an untrusted environnement

By "untrusted environnement" I mean the browser itself. You have to understand that any code executed in the browser can be corrupted by a medium/good JS developper. 
Data security suffer the same threat: giving access to data from your client means that you do not control anymore who is using it.

Once you've dealt with this simple matter, it became easier to decide what must stay on server side, and what can be deported to client.

That said, there are various ways to make data/algorithm steal more difficult:

1. Obfuscation that comes with minification
2. Double data validation (forms for example): both client and server side
3. Authentication protocols, like OAuth
4. Binary over webSockets, instead of plain json and ajax call...

The browser sandbox imposes some limitations, but mainly to protect the local computer from damages due to malicious JS code. It does not protect your code nor your data from being seen and manipulated by the user itself.

Answer (score 2):

I am using angular for some of my projects. I haven't used other frameworks , but in angular you usually consume an API to get the data. You don't query your database directly. So, the responsability of securing your data is more in you API (Backend) than in your angular client.

You can use OAUTH, or other security method that you want to make your api safe.

Comment: thank you,regarding querying data, I saw it here http://www.breezejs.com/

Comment: @INgeeg: It says "*Client caching*", not "*clientside storage*"

Comment: @INgeeg I have used breeze. This framework help queryng data from an API. I think that it doesn't let you to query your dabase directly. It allows you make advanced query from your client, but over you Api. You can secure your api, and it would be still safe.

Comment: So let's say I am writing code in asp.net mvc, in that case will angularjs help me?

Comment: You can mix both, but would be more useful if you use ASp .net Web API to make a REST API and consume that data from an alguna client.

Comment: I appreciate all your suggestions.